Encriptar String en Typescript con Cripto js y luego desencriptar con PHP Open_ssl
Estoy intentando encriptar un string en una app hecha con angular, utilizo la librería cripto js para ello, para posteriormente recibo dicho string en php para desencriptarlo, pero no funciona correctamente.
Esta es la  función que utilizo en angular
la palabra a encriptar es:  clave
   private key: string = 'llavesecreta';
     

  encryptData(value: string): string {
    // Convertir la clave a un objeto WordArray
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(CryptoJS.SHA256(this.key).toString());

    // Encriptar el valor usando AES y la clave
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
    });

    // Devolver el valor encriptado como string en Base64
    return encrypted.toString();
  }

Aqui la utilizo:
let otraClave = this.encrypt.aesEncrypt("clave");
console.log(otraClave);

el resultado de esta funcion es
it5wKeoo6vsLNC+hrk7/Dg==

Ahora en php recibo este string (que están en base64) y lo paso a la siguiente función:
if(extension_loaded('openssl')){
        
    function decryptData($value,$key){
        $encrypt_method = "aes-256-ecb";
        $key = hash('sha256', $key,true);
        $decrypttext = openssl_decrypt($value, $encrypt_method, $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING );
        if ($decrypttext === false) {
            echo "Error de OpenSSL: " . openssl_error_string();
            return false;
        }
       return $decrypttext;
    }
  
}

$key = "llavesecreta";
$Tclave = "clave";
$decryptedMessage = decryptData(base64_decode($Tclave), $key);
echo "Mensaje desencriptado: " . $decryptedMessage;
die();
    

Error:

Error de OpenSSL: error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decryptMensaje
desencriptado:

Adicionalmente:
versión de php 8.2
Edit: he creado una función en php para encriptar  la palabra "clave" utilizando la key "llavesecreta"
function encryptData($value, $key) {
        // Convertir la clave a un formato adecuado
        $key = hex2bin(hash('sha256', $key));
    
        // Configurar el método de encriptación y el relleno
        $encrypt_method = "aes-256-ecb";
        $options = 0;
    
        // Encriptar el valor
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($value, $encrypt_method, $key, $options);
    
        if ($encrypted === false) {
            echo "Error de OpenSSL: " . openssl_error_string();
            return false;
        }
    
        // Devolver el valor encriptado
        return base64_encode($encrypted);
    }
  
  encryptData("clave", "llavesecreta");

resultado:
cTZabW81WkRUVnZtYUJzZGRmd1A0Zz09

Si paso este string a la funcion decryptData(base64_decode("cTZabW81WkRUVnZtYUJzZGRmd1A0Zz09), "llavesecreta");
devulve la palabra clave
En resumen, estoy haciendo algo mal en typeScript

por que deberian ser iguales??? la encriptacion es de dos vias??? o de una via???

Hola @FranciscoNuñezIALover la encriptación es de una sola via.

bueno pero entonces hay esta el problema ... esta relacionado con diferencias en la implementación de los algoritmos de cifrado entre CryptoJS en Angular y OpenSSL en PHP, así como la configuración de los modos de cifrado y el relleno utilizado. no son iguales, son tecnologias diferentes, no entiendo en que te basas para esperar que el resultado sea identico, si sobre todo es encriptacion de una sola via.

de salida en Angular, estás utilizando el modo ECB y el relleno PKCS7, mientras que en PHP estás utilizando el modo aes-256-ecb .... que si o si son diferentes implementaciones ... a menos que venga un experto y diga que me equivoco no lo vas a conseguir como lo haces ... la unica forma que se me ocurre es generar en uno de los dos lados la encriptacion y compartir los datos ...

Funcion Typescript

private key: string = 'llavesecreta';

encryptData(value: string): string {
  // Convertir la clave a un objeto WordArray
  const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(
    CryptoJS.SHA256(this.key).toString()
  );

  // Encriptar el valor usando AES y la clave
  const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
  });

  // Devolver el valor encriptado como string en Base64
  return encrypted.toString();
}

Resultado  para la palabra "clave"
 QImbnNJfomfQKIdfm4q9NQ==

función php

function decryptData($value, $key) {

  // Convertir la clave a un formato adecuado
  $key = hex2bin(hash('sha256', $key));

  // Configurar el método de encriptación y el relleno
  $encrypt_method = "aes-256-ecb";
  $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;

  // Desencriptar el valor
  $decrypttext = openssl_decrypt(
    base64_decode($value),
    $encrypt_method,
    $key,
    $options
  );

  if ($decrypttext === false) {
    echo "Error de OpenSSL: " . openssl_error_string();
    return false;
  }

  // Quitar el relleno
  $decrypttext = rtrim($decrypttext, "\0");

  return $decrypttext;
}

llamada
$decryptedMessage = decryptData(
  `QImbnNJfomfQKIdfm4q9NQ==`,
  "llavesecreta"
);

Resultado para el string QImbnNJfomfQKIdfm4q9NQ==
clave


Si esto resuelve el problema, te sugiero que incluyas una explicacion de que fue lo que realizaste, que implementaste que soluciono el problema

Deberías hacer base64_decode dentro de la función decryptData ya que siempre va a ser necesario. ¿Ya resolviste las funciones inversas en cada lenguaje?

No  he resuelto la función inversa en Typescript (En php si) ya que es una app móvil en ´ionic´, solo enviara datos. y nunca recibirá. Gracias por tu concejo editare el codigo.

Creó que es por la incompatibilidad entre la función de encriptación en TypeScript y la función de desencriptación en PHP. Ambas funciones utilizan diferentes métodos de padding, lo que impide que la desencriptación en PHP obtenga el resultado correcto.
En TypeScript:
Se utiliza la librería CryptoJS para encriptar el string usando AES con modo ECB y padding ZeroPadding.
El resultado de la encriptación se convierte a Base64 para su posterior transmisión a PHP.
En PHP:
Se utiliza la función openssl_decrypt() para desencriptar el string recibido de Base64.
Se especifica el método de encriptación como "aes-256-ecb" y se utiliza padding OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING.
Solución:
Consiste en modificar el padding utilizado en la encriptación de TypeScript para que coincida con el padding utilizado en la desencriptación de PHP.
Sugiero que modifiques la función encryptData() para utilizar padding PKCS7 en lugar de ZeroPadding
Creo que se pueda hacer, con algo como esto:
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

No es necesario realizar cambios en la función decryptData(), ya que está configurada correctamente para manejar padding PKCS7.
En caso de que aún no funcione, recomiendo asegurarte de que la clave en TS y PHP, son la misma.
